# Postgres job fails when executed against a database other than the default postgres database

Tags: postgresql

Job fails with error "Couldn't get a connection to the database!" when the database selected is anything other than the postgres database. If the job is set to run a step with a connection to the postgres database it executes successfully. The agent runs under the postgres user.

Comment: What attempts have you made so far to solve your problem?

Comment: What do the postgres server logs say? This could be an HBA issue or a `connect` privilege issue on the other databases. The server logs should tell you exactly what the cause of the failure is.

Comment: What kind of "Job"? How do you start it? What does it do? What scheduler are you using to run that "job"? (Postgres has no built-in job scheduler)